# What is the right way to design an adventure game with PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have started development on a small 2d adventure side view game together with a couple of people. The game will consist of the regular elements: A room, a main character, an inventory, npcs, items and puzzles. We've chosen PyGame since we all are familiar with python from before. My question is quite theoretical, but how would we design this in a good way? Would every object on the screen talk to some main loop that blits everything to the screen?
(Hope this question isn't too discussion-y)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Adventure Writing System - http://home.fuse.net/wolfonenet/PAWS.htm - might be useful

http://proquestcombo.safaribooksonline.com/1592000770 may also be useful